# Django form creates new instance instead updating a existing one

Tags: python, django

I've seen this question asked a lot of time here but I can't figure out why it doesn't work in my case.
I have the following view code:

```
def edit(request, coffee_id=None):
coffee = get_object_or_404(Drink, pk=coffee_id) if coffee_id else Drink()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CoffeeForm(request.POST, instance=coffee)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('coffee:index'))
else:
    form = CoffeeForm(instance=coffee)

return render(request, 'edit.html', {'coffee_form': form})
```

This is supposed to create a new instance of coffee or to update a new one if coffee_id given in argument exists in database.

However even if coffee_id exists in database a new instance of coffee is always created.

I also tried to save the coffee instance without saving the form but it does the same.

Is there something that i'm doing wrong ? Should I set something special in the model to allow update ?

**Edit**

This is the Drink form

```
class CoffeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Drink
    fields = ('time', 'location', 'type')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    coffee_category = Category.objects.get(name='coffee')
    coffee_drink_types = DrinkType.objects.filter(category=coffee_category.id)
    self.fields['type'].choices = ((x.id, str(x)) for x in coffee_drink_types)
```

And the Drink model:

```
class Drink(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField('time', default=datetime.datetime.now)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    type = models.ForeignKey(DrinkType)
```

** Edit **

Add the urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^edit/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<coffee_id>[0-9]*)/$', views.edit, name='edit')
]
```

Comment: Can you show the CoffeeForm and the Drink model itself?

Comment: I edited the post. Thx

Comment: Are you sure that `coffee_id` is being passed to the view? Can you show your urls?

Comment: I added the urls, i think it's correctly passed to the view as the form is pre-filled with the coffee data. Just that when i save it again (changed or not), it creates a new entry instead of updating the new one

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CoffeeForm`,  not `ModelForm` when calling `super`.

```
class CoffeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Drink
        fields = ('time', 'location', 'type')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CoffeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You're right thx for your remark. However I still have new entries created :)

Answer (score 0):

get_object_or_404 errors out if the Drink with the given id doesn't exist.

Are you sure POSTing is done against /edit/1? Because if the form action doesn't have the ID, a new Drink is created.

I'd recommend you go with separate create and edit views. Possibly use class based views, but if you have reasons not to use them, something like this could work:

```
def create_coffee(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CoffeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            coffee = form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('edit_coffee', kwargs={'coffee_id': coffee.pk}))
    else:
        form = CoffeeForm()

    return render(request, 'create.html', {'coffee_form': form})


def edit_coffee(request, coffee_id=None):
    coffee = Drink.objects.filter(pk=coffee_id).first()
    if not coffee:
        return redirect(reverse('create_coffee'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CoffeeForm(request.POST, instance=coffee)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        else:
            form = CoffeeForm(instance=coffee)

        return render(request, 'edit.html', {'coffee_form': form})
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I thought it would be possible to have a single view to edit and create objects with django but maybe it's not a good pattern ... Also i don't see the code in `edit_coffee` method that could fix the creation instead update issue.

Comment: See if you're POSTing against /edit/123? You can probably figure it out with a few print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still checking this issue, I found this looking for this same issue, and I managed to solve this. 
In my case the issue was that I used the same template for both the new and existing objects, and the form was going back and creating new instances, I resolved this creating multiple views at this moment with multiple templates.

The point where I got on track was when I removed my `action="/add"` from my form and I saw that nothing happens :). I see that you are using the same templates and not changing it from the view so you may need to do this also.
If you can't solve this post your template(s) and I'm happy to help, because it may help me as well learning django! :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, my reason was in overriding default method form.save() in forms.py. So I decided to make 2 methods (for save and updating). Update method should inheirt from default save() method

`super(ArticleForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

It's not necessary but need for my, because i should to save some data not from forms.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    new_article = Article.objects.create(
        title=self.cleaned_data['title'],
        text=self.cleaned_data['text'],
        image=self.cleaned_data['image'],
        author_id=self._user.id
    )
return new_article

def update(self, article_id, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ArticleForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    new_article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    return new_article
```

this methods could return nothing, but i need new_article object in views.py

But you could do another way. Just define author_id field in def **init** of your form.

Here you could know more about it: [Habr](https://qna.habr.com/q/237066)